Questions about variables in Arm64 Assembly on MacOS
So I'm trying to start coding in arm64 assembly on my mac (it's M2), but I've run into some trouble with using variables and have a few questions:

From what I understand I declare variables in the .data section of my code, but how would I differentiate between variables and constants?
How do I declare the type of my variable? Like in C++ I write int, char...
I'm trying to print a number following a tutorial online, but when I go print the number, nothing prints. The code compiles successfully and runs, but just doesn't print, so how would I print out the number without using its ascii representation?
I know that to load information from the .data section I need to do:

adrp x1, num@page
add x1, x1, num@pageoff

but say I updated the value of num (add x1, x1, #1), how would I update the value of num in the .data section?

Assembly doesn't have variables or types. It has addresses and bytes.

I think you're very confused about what assembly language is. There is no such thing, per se, as declaring a variable except via your comments. You are free to take a memory location, treat it as a sequence of bytes in one instruction and then as an integer in the next.
If you want, you can place constants in your .text section.  But if they're in .data, the only thing making them constants is that you don't change their value.
As for your code.  You have not loaded num into x1, you've loaded the address of num into x1.  The complete instructions would be:
adrp x1, num@page
add x1, x1, num@pageoff
ldr x2, [x1]
add x2, x2, #1
str x2, [x1]

You have not told us how you're trying to write out the value, so there's no way we can help you. Are you linking in the C library or trying to run it "bare"?

So say I wanted to print the following: var: .dword 10. How would I do this using the following function structure I used for a hello world program:
.global _start
.align 4

_start:
        mov x0, #1
 adrp x1, msg@page
 add x1, x1, msg@pageoff
 mov x2, #13
 mov x16, #4
        svc #0x80

 mov x0,#0
 mov x16, #1
 svc #0x80

.data:
        msg: .ascii "Hello World!\n

So how would I print the value at the following memory location or the memory location itself: num: .dword 10

There is no svc call that converts an integer into its corresponding ascii and prints it.  You will need to write that yourself.  Alternatively, you could write print_int in C code (fairly straightforward using printf) and just have your assembly code call C code.
